# Why does this Objective-C code raise a malloc error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c

I used this method to encode base64 string in object-c, but the app was crashed sometimes:

```
- (NSString *) base64Encode
{
    //Point to start of the data and set buffer sizes
    int inLength = [self length];
    int outLength = ((((inLength * 4)/3)/4)*4) + (((inLength * 4)/3)%4 ? 4 : 0);
    const char *inputBuffer = [self bytes];
    char *outputBuffer = malloc(outLength);
    outputBuffer[outLength] = 0;

    //64 digit code
    static char Encode[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    //start the count
    int cycle = 0;
    int inpos = 0;
    int outpos = 0;
    char temp;

    //Pad the last to bytes, the outbuffer must always be a multiple of 4
    outputBuffer[outLength-1] = '=';
    outputBuffer[outLength-2] = '=';

    /* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64
     Text content   M           a           n
     ASCII          77          97          110
     8 Bit pattern  01001101    01100001    01101110

     6 Bit pattern  010011  010110  000101  101110
     Index          19      22      5       46
     Base64-encoded T       W       F       u
     */

    while (inpos < inLength){
        switch (cycle) {
            case 0:
                outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xFC)>>2];
                cycle = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                temp = (inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x03)<<4;
                outputBuffer[outpos] = Encode[temp];
                cycle = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[temp|(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xF0)>> 4];
                temp = (inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x0F)<<2;
                outputBuffer[outpos] = Encode[temp];
                cycle = 3;                  
                break;
            case 3:
                outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[temp|(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xC0)>>6];
                cycle = 4;
                break;
            case 4:
                outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x3f];
                cycle = 0;
                break;                          
            default:
                cycle = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    NSString *pictemp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:outputBuffer];
    free(outputBuffer); 
    return pictemp;

}
```

The error is :

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x164084: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

and when I debug, it stop in this line:

```
free(outputBuffer);
```

Do you know what caused crash here ?

Comment: You should enable Guard Malloc (alt+cmd+R, tab "Diagnostics", check "Enable Guard Malloc") to see if you're having a buffer overflow.

Comment: simple anser: why? because it's C with a lot of syntactic sugar!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is the problem:

```
char *outputBuffer = malloc(outLength);
outputBuffer[outLength] = 0;
```

In the first line you allocate `outLength` bytes, but in the second line you write to a position one byte beyond the end of the buffer. Depending on page boundaries and other mysterious happenings inside `malloc`, that might be OK or it might not. That would explain why it doesn't crash *every* time.

Try this instead:

```
char *outputBuffer = malloc(outLength + 1);
outputBuffer[outLength] = 0;
```

That might fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You modify past the end of your malloc'd outputBuffer with:

```
outputBuffer[outLength] = 0;
```

If outLength is 3, then you can set `outputBuffer[0]`, `outputBuffer[1]`, and `outputBuffer[2]` but not `outputBuffer[3]`.

Either change your malloc to:

```
char *outputBuffer = malloc(outLength+1);
```

Or change your initialization to:

```
outputBuffer[outLength-1] = 0;
```

Comment: You don't want to use `outputBuffer[outLength-1]` since `outLength` is computed and we may need to write that much into the string.

Comment: Unless you increase outLength to allow for it in the previous statement but even if you don't it would be far better than changing memory outside your malloc'd block. It might not give you the answer you want but it would'nt crash!

Comment: @LavaSlider Sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant of your either/or you definitely wanted the "either" and not the "or".